# Android studio fragment or new activity

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, android-studio

I have some activity(7-10) in my application and each of them has a common part (1/4 activities is common, 3/4 is totally different and a little complicated - a lot of buttons, images, lists etc.). Should I create one activity and 7-10 fragments and this is not too much so accplicattion won't be able to lags? I would like to avoid the effect of the common part will be refresh. What is the best way to solve this problem? One activity and some fragments or something with actiivty transition animation(is it possible to made effect that common part isn't refresh?-without any animation?)?

Answer (score 2):

you can  put all your common parts in An activity , and put the replaceable content as fragments . 
this way you will load one activity with all common elements once instead of 7-10 times

Edit 
you can use a code like this related to a button to change the fragment :

```
 Fragment fragment = new Dashboard();
 FragmentManager fragmentManager = activity.getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment).commit(); 
// replacing the existing fragment  to the content frame
```

Comment: So better way is one activity and some fragments? Is it possible to change fragment A by click on button on this fragment and replace it for fragment B?

Comment: I edited my answer and add a sample  code :) check it out